# characters appear with question marks when inside html tag attributes

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, exif

My application allows users to upload an image with "embedded" captions. These captions are taken from the exif data:

```
foreach (exif_read_data('image.jpg', 0, true) as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        if ($key == 'IFD0' && $name == 'Title') {
            $caption = $val;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($caption !== '') { break; }
}
//save $caption to database
```

The images are displayed along with their captions. Each image's caption is rendered 2 times:

1. `title` attribute of an `<a>` that is wrapped around the image
2. in a `div` that contains the caption

This is the result:

```
<a title="T?h?i?s? ?i?s? ?a? ?c?a?p?t?i?o?n?" href="#"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
<div class="caption">This is a caption.</div>
```

As you can see, when the caption is inside the `title` attribute, question marks appear. Why is this so?

I would note that I have made the whole application work with utf8 (database, html pages). I have also tried to `utf8_encode()` the extracted caption before saving it into the database, to no avail.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
By the way, the reason for using an `<a>` is so that the image appears in a jQuery lightbox when clicked.

**EDIT:**
@tpaksu, here is an actual dump of the result of `exif_read_data('image.jpg', 0, true)`

```
Array
(
    [FILE] => Array
        (
            [FileName] => 174.jpg
            [FileDateTime] => 1332196128
            [FileSize] => 236179
            [FileType] => 2
            [MimeType] => image/jpeg
            [SectionsFound] => ANY_TAG, IFD0, EXIF, GPS, WINXP
        )

    [COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="640" height="427"
            [Height] => 427
            [Width] => 640
            [IsColor] => 1
            [ByteOrderMotorola] => 1
            [CCDWidth] => 9mm
            [ApertureFNumber] => f/11.0
            [UserComment] => 
            [UserCommentEncoding] => UNDEFINED
        )

    [IFD0] => Array
        (
            [ImageDescription] => STATE OF CALAMITY/FEB. 2, 2012: Firemen and residents of sitio San Roque in Talisay City help each other in putting off the fire. The Talisay City council wants to declare sitio Laray in a state of calamity.(CDN PHOTO/JUNJIE MENDOZA)
            [Make] => Canon
            [Model] => Canon EOS 50D
            [Orientation] => 1
            [Software] => Adobe Photoshop CS2 Windows
            [DateTime] => 2012:02:04 18:54:15
            [YCbCrPositioning] => 1
            [UndefinedTag:0x1001] => 4752
            [UndefinedTag:0x1002] => 3168
            [Exif_IFD_Pointer] => 2544
            [GPS_IFD_Pointer] => 5304
            [Title] => S�T�A�T�E� �O�F� �C�A�L�A�M�I�T�Y�/�F�E�B�.� �2�,� �2�0�1�2�:� �F�i�r�e�m�e�n� �a�n�d� �r�e�s�i�d�e�n�t�s� �o�f� �s�i�t�i�o� �S�a�n� �R�o�q�u�e� �i�n� �T�a�l�i�s�a�y� �C�i�t�y� �h�e�l�p� �e�a�c�h� �o�t�h�e�r� �i�n� �p�u�t�t�i�n�g� �o�f�f� �t�h�e� �f�i�r�e�.� �T�h�e� �T�a�l�i�s�a�y� �C�i�t�y� �c�o�u�n�c�i�l� �w�a�n�t�s� �t�o� �d�e�c�l�a�r�e� �s�i�t�i�o� �L�a�r�a�y� �i�n� �a� �s�t�a�t�e� �o�f� �c�a�l�a�m�i�t�y�.�(�C�D�N� �P�H�O�T�O�/�J�U�N�J�I�E� �M�E�N�D�O�Z�A�)���
            [Subject] => S�T�A�T�E� �O�F� �C�A�L�A�M�I�T�Y�/�F�E�B�.� �2�,� �2�0�1�2�:� �F�i�r�e�m�e�n� �a�n�d� �r�e�s�i�d�e�n�t�s� �o�f� �s�i�t�i�o� �S�a�n� �R�o�q�u�e� �i�n� �T�a�l�i�s�a�y� �C�i�t�y� �h�e�l�p� �e�a�c�h� �o�t�h�e�r� �i�n� �p�u�t�t�i�n�g� �o�f�f� �t�h�e� �f�i�r�e�.� �T�h�e� �T�a�l�i�s�a�y� �C�i�t�y� �c�o�u�n�c�i�l� �w�a�n�t�s� �t�o� �d�e�c�l�a�r�e� �s�i�t�i�o� �L�a�r�a�y� �i�n� �a� �s�t�a�t�e� �o�f� �c�a�l�a�m�i�t�y�.�(�C�D�N� �P�H�O�T�O�/�J�U�N�J�I�E� �M�E�N�D�O�Z�A�)���
            [UndefinedTag:0xEA1C] => �����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
        )

    [EXIF] => Array
        (
            [ExposureTime] => 1/125
            [FNumber] => 11/1
            [ISOSpeedRatings] => 400
            [ExifVersion] => 0221
            [DateTimeOriginal] => 2012:02:02 12:40:00
            [DateTimeDigitized] => 2012:02:02 12:40:00
            [ComponentsConfiguration] => �
            [ShutterSpeedValue] => 458752/65536
            [ApertureValue] => 458752/65536
            [ExposureBiasValue] => 0/1
            [Flash] => 16
            [FocalLength] => 16/1
            [UserComment] => ������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
            [SubSecTimeOriginal] => 00
            [SubSecTimeDigitized] => 00
            [FlashPixVersion] => 0100
            [ColorSpace] => 1
            [ExifImageWidth] => 2000
            [ExifImageLength] => 1333
            [FocalPlaneXResolution] => 4752000/894
            [FocalPlaneYResolution] => 3168000/597
            [FocalPlaneResolutionUnit] => 2
            [CustomRendered] => 0
            [ExposureMode] => 1
            [WhiteBalance] => 0
            [SceneCaptureType] => 0
            [UndefinedTag:0xEA1C] => �������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
        )

    [GPS] => Array
        (
            [GPSVersion] => ��
        )

    [WINXP] => Array
        (
            [Title] => STATE OF CALAMITY/FEB. 2, 2012: Firemen and residents of sitio San Roque in Talisay City help each other in putting off the fire. The Talisay City council wants to declare sitio Laray in a state of calamity.(CDN PHOTO/JUNJIE MENDOZA)
            [Subject] => STATE OF CALAMITY/FEB. 2, 2012: Firemen and residents of sitio San Roque in Talisay City help each other in putting off the fire. The Talisay City council wants to declare sitio Laray in a state of calamity.(CDN PHOTO/JUNJIE MENDOZA)
        )

)
```

Comment: Possibly the text's in utf-16 format? But I  can't see why it'd show up with `?` in one spot and not the other if your output source is the same in both cases.

Comment: The texts are set using "File Info" in Photoshop

Comment: I'm not sure if EXIF data has a prescribed character set for text or whether it's up to the application to determine the charset when parsing it. Have you tried detecting the character set that the EXIF data is in?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: What is the value in the database? What is the dump of the exif data (var_dump or print_r please)?

Comment: @tpaksu: I've added the actual dump

Comment: Ok, its coming from the exif data then. Are you using WinXP? here they say something about it. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php#77586

Comment: @GordonM: `mb_detect_encoding()` returns `ASCII`

Comment: @tpaksu: it says `Compiling both exif and mbstring statically (--enable-exif --enable-mbstring) resolves the issue.` Sorry, how do I do that? I'm using XAMPP on Win7, but yes I think the exif data are set by Photoshop on a WinXP machine.

Comment: There are much easier ways. No need to recompile PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok try this inside your code.

```
 if ($key == 'IFD0' && $name == 'Title') {
     if(strpos($val,"�")>0){
         for($i=0;$i<len($val);$i++){
             $newval.=$val[i];
             $i++;
         }
     }
     $caption = $val;
     break;
 }
```

or

```
 if ($key == 'IFD0' && $name == 'Title') {
     $caption = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $val);
     break;
 }
```

Comment: This is at best only removing symptoms and at worst it will ruin a [proper UCS-2 encoding](https://exiv2.org/tags.html) of text which can also be non-ASCII.

Comment: I agree, that time I gave this answer, I wasn't aware of converting encodings before processing. Use the second answer that contains iconv.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 seems to encode IFD0 tags using UTF-16 Little Endian, so you can also try parsing those values with **iconv()** and **trim()** the resulting string *just in case*:

```
$exif_data = exif_read_data( $file, NULL, true, false );
    if ( isset( $exif_data['IFD0'] ) ) {
        $title  = trim(iconv('UTF-16LE','UTF-8',$ifd0['Title']));
    }
```

Of course it would be wise to make sure your system provides UTF-16LE and UTF-8

Comment: Correct would be [UCS-2](https://exiv2.org/tags.html) instead of UTF-16, which means you can never have/expect Emojis in there.